# Please reopen a question I asked

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post:

[Classical limit in quantum mechanics proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653251/)

Please reopen this question. I tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have reopened the edited question.